# Slow local queries

Tags: database, mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

Using AWS' DocumentDB, I've deployed a test database cluster in Germany. When I run a test-query on it from an EC2 instance in Germany, it takes less than a 2 seconds. When I query it from my country (middle-east) it takes more then a minute.

This is the simple test I run (it just goes through the whole collection):

```
var last_doc= db.dev.find()
while(last_doc.hasNext()){  last_doc = last_doc.next(); }
```

Thing is, we also have an RDS (MySQL) DB in AWS and a query of the same size takes less than 2 seconds from my country to RDS (Also in Germany).

I tried viewing the logs so I followed [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/profiling.html) but I can't seem to find any logs from `docdb` in CloudWatch. [These are my cluster parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJxFR.jpg). I also tried opening a ticket with AWS but apparently our basic subscription doesn't allow creating tickets.

Does anyone happen to have suggestion on how to tackle this? What should I do/look for?

Thanks ahead!

Comment: How are you connecting to DocumentDb in Germany from Middle-east ? Can you try the same query with findOne or find with limit of 10 and check the query latency from germany and middle-east ?